# Trigger Step functions without eventbridge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

My team are required to kick off a Step Function in AWS for a machine learning application.

In my organisation eventBridge is not allowed to be used (politics around adoption of certain technologies) - and the same is with cloud watch events as this is using the same API as eventbridge, both are blocked.

We do have access to Cloudwatch Alarms, SNS, Lambda, Glue, S3, lambda, step functions.

How could we create a schedule that was able to periodically (say once a day, or every 5 minutes) trigger the step function that DOESN’T use event bridge?

Thanks,
Alex

We are not able to use
-Eventbridge
-Cloudwatch Events
-Maintenance Window in Systems Manager

Comment: Use a local cron that uses the AWS cli to start the step function

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you use EventBridge? Could you please provide the reason behind this decision?

Comment: @Paolo hi mate, well I’m not too sure how realistic this would be for production. We’re not meant to be directly accessing the instances in Prod. Also, I’m not sure how retry logic would work if an execution failed for example, if some data was missing and the kedro node (python framework we are using) couldn’t execute how could Cron deal with this scenario?

Comment: @diegosantiviago there is another technology that is non aws the company wants us to adopt but doesn’t apply for our use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parent state machine that has a wait state and after that you call StartExecution from there, using service integrations. The problem is that the max duration of the parent workflow is 1 year.